# Authentication and authorization of FHIR server

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, hl7-fhir

I have spinned of a azure service for fhir. I want to use it with a .NET core API and I want to control the authentication and authorization inside the API. I haven't found an example where I can authenticate the webapi in azure without prompting for username and password with clientid, client secret and tenantID. And also regarding authorization, is there a way to restrict a tenant to only access certain group of patients with FHIR ?

Comment: What do you mean `without prompting for username and password with clientid, client secret and tenantID`? You mean you don't want to use all of them to auth or just use `clientid, client secret and tenantID` to auth?

Comment: @JoyWang I don't want to answer a prompt, I want to use anything that will get me a token through API.

Comment: what client app do you want to use? confidential or public or service client application?

Comment: @JoyWang For now, it is just the API that I am working on, API will have all the configurations in json for getting the token from azure AD and getting data from FHIR. I would expose the API for client applications to access.

Comment: @Abhijithponnapally check the client credential flow within Oauth 2.0, here you have code samples from Microsoft: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2 dec
Read also about right Azure Ad model: simple Azure Ad, Azure Ad B2B or Azure Ad B2C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Active Directory [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain a token to access the Azure API for FHIR. In order to do this, you will need to [register a service client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-service-azure-ad-client-app) in Azure AD. Once you have a service client application (and a secret), you can obtain a token from Azure AD with something like:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

with the following fields in the payload:

```
client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
&scope=https://<myfhirservice.azurehealthcareapis.com/.default
&client_secret=abcdef1234
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

You can then present that token to the FHIR API with the `Authorization: Bearer xwy...` header field.

The service principal associated with the service client application has to be granted access to the the FHIR API. It is recommended that you set that up using [Azure RBAC configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/configure-azure-rbac), but if you are using a different tenant from the the associated with your Azure Subscription, you will need to do [local RBAC configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/configure-local-rbac).

At the moment there is no way to do "granular" access control (e.g. only certain patients). It is recommended that you implement such logic using an API management service such as [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/api-management/) or similar.